# Want to update only child prop of React Bootstrap Tabs, but it is re-rendering the map again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lazy-loading, react-bootstrap

I've the below code in `ControlledTabs` file

```
const ControlledTabs = ({ data }) => {
  const [eventKey, setEventKey] = useState(data[0]?.eventKey)
  const [children, setChildren] = useState(data[0]?.children)

  return (
    <Tabs className="m-0 p-0 mb-2"
      variant={variant}
      activeKey={eventKey}
      onSelect={(e) => {
        const selectedTab = data.filter(tab => tab?.eventKey === e)[0]
        setEventKey(selectedTab?.eventKey)
        setChildren(selectedTab?.children)
        console.log(selectedTab)
      }}
      defaultActiveKey={data[0]?.eventKey}
      justify fill
    >
      {useMemo(()=>data.map(TabData => (
        <Tab
          key={TabData.eventKey} eventKey={TabData.eventKey} title={TabData.title}
        >
          {console.log('rendering')}
          {children}
        </Tab>
      )))
      }
    </Tabs >
  );
}
```

I'm using the 1st eventKey and child as default prop, so onload of the page it'll load the tab.

But On Select of the tab, it is rendering the 5 times since I'm having 5 objects in array with values.

***I probably need only the default tab child to be loaded but the tab titles should be displayed.***

***How to render only the child object of the Tab, which is inside the map?***

Comment: does the prop `mountOnEnter` for `Tabs` component fix your issue?

Comment: I didn't use any mountOnEnter Props, since I'm using component level of React. So using useState Hook to set state and trying to use useMemo hook just to update only child.

Comment: ```
<Tabs className="m-0 p-0 mb-2"
      variant={variant}
      activeKey={eventKey}
      onSelect={(e) => {
        const selectedTab = data.filter(tab => tab?.eventKey === e)[0]
        setEventKey(selectedTab?.eventKey)
        setChildren(selectedTab?.children)
        console.log(selectedTab)
      }}
      defaultActiveKey={data[0]?.eventKey}
      justify fill
      mountOnEnter
    >
```